# unable to implement basic login in the django framework

Tags: django, authentication

I am trying as hard as I can to learn to concept of authentication within the Django framework. I am reading the documentation and trying to code similar which will help me get the subject. At the moment I am trying to implement a simple login which redirects to a page. If the user is logged in he should see a message other wise he should see a different message. This is my code.

I have made a simple login form

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

this is my login view

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/users/success/')
            else:
                return redirect('/users/success/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'testauth/login.html', {'form': form})
```

(I know the above code is a little bit redundant ... at the moment this is not so important)

and this is the success view

```
def success_view(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponse("logged in")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("you are not logged in")
```

The problem is, I always get the "logged in" message even with users which do not exist. I tried restarting the server my cache is disabled ... I have no idea why is this happening. Why is this happening?

(p.s. I do not want to set in the settings.py a login success url. I want to do everything manually because I am struggling a lot with this topic and I want to make sure that I truly understand everything)

Comment: Both in case the `user is not None`, and the user is `None`, you redirect to `/users/success/`...

Comment: Have you tried using the built in log out feature? Also why are you redirecting it to say logged in or out, why not use an {% if %} inside of the html code?

Comment: I know that in both case I redirect to the success view. As I mentioned above some of the code is redundant. However, in the success view I first check if the user is authenticated and for some reason it always returns true.

Comment: Looks like the user's are being authenticated automatically. Which would always show as success.

Comment: What do you get for `print(request.user)`?

Comment: This is so stupid I just had to laugh really loud. I forgot to logout. Otherwise everything is working just fine. Thanks for the help.